# Why isn't Linq xml OrderBy working for me?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sql-order-by

I've got the following XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <invoice xmlns="http://www.jemos.co.uk/xsds/experiments">
<header date="2012-12-27T13:17:03.652Z" invoiceId="0yFUWhwmHH">
    <seller name="euxz0bIqiC">
        <address line1="fxWDfaMu8O" line2="u5LmqdrH6f" line3="5c7XVSiXCh"
            city="CyCJOexD1v" postcode="Td4RmntPah" country="_vzVd1oo1Z" />
    </seller>
    <buyer name="UKNWLox8WE">
        <address line1="6RcK4QKz94" line2="U04UEsRMjh" line3="lnSWe9NY0r"
            city="g5nj0tbJbx" postcode="evyno9yUR6" country="rpIgh2XDIo" />
    </buyer>
</header>
<details>
    <items>
        <item id="ZBV9eUw0MS" description="h_x4Lqr2bp" quantity="1356614223664"
            price="0.552495629185551" currency="NdqzH508tA" />
        <item id="HNAQbfAXrv" description="sTgStzKny7" quantity="1356614223666"
            price="0.10527685341195969" currency="tvJUSZjipG" />
        <item id="ikJ0y_8TdZ" description="RUXb6n7cMJ" quantity="1356614223667"
            price="0.8693868918655814" currency="8LHywfSuC7" />
        <item id="lbdLaiI7zK" description="B_kId9Er07" quantity="1356614223668"
            price="0.9610746134524019" currency="bJvcOByXzx" />
        <item id="fBRl89ir8K" description="CuUiyjfFrz" quantity="1356614223669"
            price="0.6002495627735738" currency="WqB4AgH6Jv" />
    </items>
</details>
```

And have got the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XMLExperiments
{
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.test);
        IEnumerable<XElement> items = xml.Descendants()
            .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName.Contains("item"));

        foreach (XElement item in items)
        {
            IEnumerable<XAttribute> attrs = item.Attributes()
                .OrderBy(at => at.Name.LocalName);                  
            foreach (XAttribute attr in attrs)
               Console.WriteLine("Attribute name: {0}", attr.Name.LocalName);

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Upon execution, I get the following:

[image]

I'd have expected "currency" to appear first, whereas all other items are correctly ordered. Something similar happens also if I order descendingly.

Any pointers?

Comment: Scroll one line back. I bet it's there.

Comment: The last 5 attributes printed out in that screenshot are in the correct order. Are you sure it's not working? It looks like the first "currency" is just scrolled off the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your output, it looks like it did.

The last few lines are:

```
currency  
description  
id  
price  
quantity
```

In your screen shot there are 4 places where "currency" exists and 5 that "quantity" exists.  All things point to the first line simply being scrolled off the top.

Comment: That's it! Thx. A bit embarassing, really. I had to scroll all the way to the top, and of course is working. Thx for the solution